# Python Multiprocessing - Object has no attribute

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing on my script. But it doesn't work. what am I doing wrong? I searched too much but I didn't find the solution. Can you help me guys?

It seems **HistogramMerger** working with multiprocessing. I saw some print-out when I run the script but I don't get any result file which I normally getting with for loop.

**I'm getting this error message:**

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'histogramAdd'
```

ps: This histogram merger script merging multiple files to one single file. And, I'm trying to run this script faster than normal. If you know better solution, please let me know.

**without multiprocessing (working)**

```
from histogram_merger import HistogramMerger

var1=697
var2=722
with HistogramMerger("results/resMergedHistograms_"+str(var1)+"_"+str(var1)+".root") as hm:
    for i in xrange(var1,var2+1):
        print "Run Number : " +str(i)
        hm.addHistogramFile("../results/run"+str(i)+"/run"+str(i)+"_histo.root")
```

**with MultiProcessing**

```
from histogram_merger import HistogramMerger
from multiprocessing import Pool

var1=697
var2=722

##################################################

arrayOfNumbers = [xx for xx in range(var1, var2+1)]
print(arrayOfNumbers)
pool = Pool(8) 

def histogramAdd(run):
    print("Run Number : "+str(run))
    hm.addHistogramFile("../results/run"+str(run)+"/run"+str(run)+"_histo.root")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with HistogramMerger("results/resMergedHistograms_"+str(var1)+"_"+str(var2)+".root") as hm: 
        pool.map(histogramAdd, arrayOfNumbers)
        pool.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is odd. `hm` is not in scope within the function `histogramAdd`. I would expect something like `NameError: name 'hm' is not defined`. Perhaps there is some `hm` import you are not showing.

Regardless, you need to pass the object to the function. You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for this. E.g.

```
from functools import partial

# ...

def histogramAdd(run, hm):  # <- extra parameter!
    print("Run Number : "+str(run))
    hm.addHistogramFile("../results/run"+str(run)+"/run"+str(run)+"_histo.root")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with HistogramMerger("results/resMergedHistograms_"+str(var1)+"_"+str(var2)+".root") as hm: 
        pool.map(partial(histogramAdd, hm), arrayOfNumbers)
        pool.join()
```